# Which is the fastest way to run this SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (let's call it A) in SQL Server 2016 that I want to query on. I need to select only those rows that have a definitive status, so I need to exclude some rows. There's another table (B), containing the record id from the Table A and two columns, col1 and col2. If these columns are non-empty, the corresponding record can be considered final. There is a one-to-one relationship between tables A and B. Because these tables are rather large, I want to use the most efficient query. Which should I choose?

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE record_id IN
  (SELECT record_id FROM TableB WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL)

SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.record_id = b.record_id
WHERE b.col1 IS NOT NULL AND b.col2 IS NOT NULL

SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
ON a.record_id = b.record_id
  AND b.col1 IS NOT NULL
  AND b.col2 IS NOT NULL
```

Of course, if there's an even faster way that I hadn't thought of, please share. I'd also be very curious to know why one query is faster than the others.

Comment: Please read Eric Lippert's excellent [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/): "... If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses. Don’t write short descriptions of the horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to guess which is faster ..."

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: I did, but the results vary. The differences are rather significant (~20%) but the faster query is not always the same...

Comment: First, check the execution plans. That's the only thing that can tell you which is faster. The same query can result in different execution plans, depending on the underlying indexes and data statistics. The query optimizer is smart enough that it will generate the **same** execution plan for different querys, as long as they are equivalent.

Comment: PS - the queries aren't equivalent. The first returns rows only from one table. The other two return rows from both tables. Finally, the `ON` clause of a `JOIN` is *not* the same as a `WHERE` statement. Check the execution plans

Comment: There you go then - you've got evidence that *no one of them is necessarily the fastest* and if there are variables that control which is fastest in a particular scenario, you've not identified what those variables are (or if you have, you've not identified them in your question) - so how do you expect us to identify a single "best" query?

Comment: Alright, I was hoping someone could provide me with some more insight about the under-the-hood differences, but these are fair answers and the article makes sense. I'll check the execution plans. Cheers!

Comment: To be fair though the queries are equivalent, I select `a.*` in the second and third queries.

Comment: The queries are not completely equivalent if there are multiple rows in TableB with the same recordID, as the IN version will only return the corresponding row from TableA once, whereas the join will return duplicates

Comment: @A.Stam Check and post the execution plans! *These* are the under-the-hood mechanisms. And the queries are *definitely* not equivalent. The first won't return any duplicate entries while the other two will

Comment: Yup, correct, but there aren't any duplicates in TableB. As I put in the original question, it's a one-on-one relationship.

Comment: Ensure that TableB is well indexed. Pull data from there since you know your data is unique and join based on your needs. Furthermore, a CTE can enhance your query's efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT b.record_id, b.col1, b.col2
FROM TableB b
WHERE col1 IS NULL
AND col2 IS NULL --if the field isn't NULL, it might be quicker to do <> '')

SELECT a.record_id, a.identifyColumnsNeededExplicitely
FROM cte
JOIN TableA a ON a.record_id = cte.record_id
ORDER BY a.record_id
```

Comment: Actually, you might want to consider doing this query FROM tableA instead of FROM cte. That should make it quicker; a CTE is allowing for the table (already filtered) to be stored in mem (most importantly, to be read only once), thus rendering the query quicker. Next step, using execution plan, index/re-index the table that is innefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In practice the execution plan will do whatever it likes depending on your current indexes / clustered index / foreign keys / constraints / table stastics (aka number of rows / general containt of your rows/...). Any analysis should be done case by case and what's true for 2 tables may not be to 2 others table.

Theorically,

Without any index, the first one should be the best since it will make an optimization on operations with 1 table scan on TableB, 2 contants scan on TableB and 1 table scan on Table1.

With a foreign key on TableA.record_id referencing TableB.record_id OR an index in both column, the second should be faster since it will make a scan index and 2 constant scan.

In rare case, it could be the 3rd one depending on TableB stats. But not far from number 2 since number 3 will scan all the TableB.

In even rarer case, neither of the 3.

What I'm tryng to say is : "Since we don't have neither your tables nor rows, open your SQL Management, put the stats ON and try it yourself."